# How to get only India city names in Google Autocomplete iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cocoa-touch, autocomplete

I want to display only city names from India in google autocomplete.

My PAI is : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=(strSearch)&country=in&language=en&key=MyKeyhare

Here example search string is : Hy (OR) Hyd

When i send : Hy.  It's displaying below city names

```
Hyderabad, Telangana, India
Hyattsville, MD, USA
Hyōgo Prefecture, Japan
Hyères, France
Hyvinkää, Finland
```

When i send : Hyd.  It's displaying below city names

```
Hyderabad, Telangana, India
Hyderabad, Pakistan
Hyde Park, Newtownabbey, UK
Hyderguda, Hyderabad, Telangana, India
Hyde Street, San Francisco, CA, USA
```

it's displaying all matching names form all countries not only from India. But i want only Indian city names. Is it possible...

let url = NSURL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=(strSearch)&country=in&language=en&key=MyKey")

```
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL) { (data, response, error) -> Void in


        do {
            if data != nil{
                let dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableLeaves) as!  NSDictionary
                //                    print(dic)
                let status = dic["status"] as! String

                if status == "REQUEST_DENIED" {
                } else if status == "ZERO_RESULTS" {
                } else if status == "INVALID_REQUEST" {
                } else {
                    let dictionary = dic["predictions"] as! NSArray
                    //                        print((dictionary[0] as! [String:Any])["description"]!)
                    for index in 0..<dictionary.count {
                        print((dictionary[index] as! [String:Any])["description"]!)
//                            print((dictionary[index] as! [String:Any])["place_id"]!)
                        self.displayItems.append((dictionary[index] as! [String:Any])["description"]! as! String)
                    }
//                        print("*******************************************")


                    }
                }

            }
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }

    task.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El Captain answer is used when you using google SDK. If you are using by API, then use this url: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=**search_str**&types=geocode&language=en&key=**api-key**&components=country:IN .

For More detail you can use my [repository](https://github.com/thedahiyaboy/TDAutocompletionTextfield) . And check the URL, the way I am doing. It is 100% working.

Any further assistance you can ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GMSAutocompleteFilter` with `country` like

```
GMSAutocompleteFilter *filter = [[GMSAutocompleteFilter alloc] init];
filter.type = kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterNoFilter;
filter.country = @"IN";
```

Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete#call_gmsplacesclient)